# how can i hide some div's from mobile browser.? and display new div's.?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mobile, detect

i had following two div's in my site,

```
<div class="desktop_1">some desktop site data 1</div>
<div class="desktop_2">some desktop site data 2</div>
```

what i am asking is, when browse this page any mobile device just disabled above two dives, and display following new div's

```
<div class="mobile_1">some mobile data 1</div>
<div class="mobile_2">some mobile data 2</div>
```

if detect mobile devices disble first two dive's then display second two div's... how can i figure it.???
i hope you got what i meant here...

thanks

Comment: [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

Comment: Check how [Bootstrap responsive utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) work, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)   )   
  {
    $(".desktop1").hide();
    $(".mobile_1").show();
   }
```

Untested code!Should work I guess...You can see more solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-handheld-device-in-jquery)

Comment: its working for mobile devices, but when test desktop .mobile_1 div still appear there, i want hide .mobile_1 div from desktop browser also

Comment: Use media queries, not client detection.

Answer (score 1):

You could try looking at [Media Queries](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) which would allow you to have them declared separately like so:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1024px) {
    .desktop_1 {
        /* Styles */
    }
    .desktop_2 {
        /* More Styles */
    }
}

@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px)
    .mobile_1 {
        /* Styles */
    }
    .mobile_2 {
        /* More Styles */
    }
}
```

And if both `div`s appear in your code and need to be hidden, you can always include the opposite media's declaration in the query for it to make it hidden, like this:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1024px) {
    .desktop_1 {
        /* Styles */
    }
    .desktop_2 {
        /* More Styles */
    }

    /* Hide Mobile on Desktop */
    .mobile_1 {
        display: none;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    .mobile_2 {
        display: none;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
```

And vice versa in the mobile declaration.

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info)